# C++ program can't start because a .dll is missing, but it should be looking for a .lib

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm using QT Creator to develop an app. Running the code in QTC results in the program crashing so I went to the path of the program's executable. When I try to run it, I get the message: "The program can't start because libname.dll is missing from your computer." This is strange because libname.dll doesn't exist, though libname.lib does.

In the .pro file of my app, the following lines were automatically inserted when linking the appropriate library:

```
    unix:!macx|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../libname/lib/ -luhd

    win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../libname/lib/uhd.lib
    else:unix:!macx|win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS +=   $$PWD/../../libname/lib/libuhd.a
```

I looked through the qmake files and there is no mention of a libname.dll so is there anything I could be missing here?

Comment: If the .lib is an import module, it's going to attempt to load its corresponding DLL.

Comment: Note that Qmake can handle `LIBS += L$$PWD/../../libname/lib/ -luhd` even on Windows.

Comment: You either need the DLL or you need a standalone library. It seems like you don't have either.

Comment: You are lacking some operating system specific (perhaps Windows, or Win32) tag

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile your library as a .dll.

Windows programs rely on .dll to run, while Linux ones rely on .lib. Your issue here is that you try to use a Linux library file on a Windows executable.

Find/build the .dll for your library using a Windows compiler (MSVC/MinGW), then put it next to your executable, the same way you did for the Qt DLLs